# Dotfuscator UWP doesn't compile with .NET Native Tool-Chain

Tags: uwp, dotfuscator, preemptive

I'm not being able to generate Microsoft Store packages using Dotfuscator.

My UWP project is targeting v10.0.15063 and I've tried with Dotfuscator CE v5.30.0.5167 and v5.32.1.6167 with no luck.

The app compiles and is obfuscated, but Native Tool-Chain compiler raises an error.

The error:

> 1>C:\Users\username\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.1\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : ILT0005: 'C:\Users\username\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.1\tools\x86\ilc\Tools\Gatekeeper.exe @"D:\ProjectFolder\obj\x86\Release\ilc\intermediate\gkargs.rsp"' returned exit code 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I get the answer myself changing Visual Studio log level to detailed, seems that .Net Native cannot compile obfuscated code yet.

> Gatekeeper warning GK0019 : GK0019 El ensamblado 'AssemblyName' está ofuscado. El compilador de Native C# todavía no es compatible con la ofuscación de código.